# Unable to connect to HBase using Java ?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Before asking this questions i searched a lot to solve the below issue but couldn't solve, if anyone can help on this.

I have installed hadoop1 2.5.0 and HBase 0.98.6 (in pseudo dist mode). I am trying to run a simple java program to retrieve data from hbase. My all nodes are running.
My code is-

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.master","hadoopHost:60000");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", hBaseZookeeperHostName);
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
System.out.println("hello");
HTableInterface table = HConnectionManager.createConnection(conf).getTable("user".getBytes());
System.out.println(table.getTableDescriptor().getColumnFamilies().toString());
```

It is printing hello and after that its getting stuck for some time and ends simply without any error or warning.

I am very new to this Big Data world, if someone can put his/her time to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways by which we can create configuration for HBase connection.

1. We can use the below lines in your Class to create a connection and then set hbase-site.xml in your classpath.

   Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create;
   HTableInterface table = HConnectionManager.createConnection(conf).getTable("user".getBytes());

By this way, the values defined in the hbase-site.xml will be used to create the connection.

2. If you want to override the values in hbase-site.xml you can remove hbase-site.xml from your classpath and set the parameter as required like you have mentioned in the above code.

Since you are trying to use the default values, I would suggest you to go with the option one.